# Why in the defn of bounded linear functional does the bound depend on $x$?

Tags: functional-analysis

If $T : X \to Y$ is a linear functional between normed spaces, we say $T$ is bounded if $\exists M > 0$ such that $||T(x)||_{Y} \leq M ||x||_{X}$ for all $x \in X$.

Usually, when we say bounded, e.g., for $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, we mean there is some $M > 0$ such that for all $x \in \Bbb R$, $|f(x)| \leq M$.  Here, the right hand side (RHS) doesn't depend on $x$.

But for some reason in the first definition, our RHS depends on $x$.  What is the reason for this?

**Edit**: If I remember correctly, we say a map $f : D_{1} \to D_{2}$ between metric spaces is bounded if there is some $M > 0$ such that $d_{2}(f(x),f(y)) \leq M d_{1}(x,y)$ for all $x, y \in D_{1}$.  If this is the correct definition, then my question applies to this scenario, too.  Why does the RHS depend on the input?

Comment: if a linear function is bounded (in traditional sense), then it is the zero function.

Comment: Ultimately, this is just a usage of the same word "bounded" to mean something different (but slightly related).  This kind of overloading happens all the time in mathematics.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for pointing that out.  So, when discussing linear maps, by bounded we mean there is some $M > 0$ such that the "magnitude" of the output cannot exceed $M$ times the "magnitude" of the input.

Comment: The thing is that a bounded map between topological vector spaces is one that maps bounded sets to bounded sets. It's a not-quite-coincidence that a linear map between normed spaces is bounded if and only if it is continuous, which led to the custom of speaking of "bounded linear maps" when "continuous linear maps" are what one is actually interested in.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the additional comment.  So when talking about a map between t.v.s., it is bounded if it takes bounded sets to bounded sets (i.e., the preimage of any bounded set is bounded? hmm, that doesn't really say what you're saying; maybe just that the image of any bounded set is bounded).  Does this definition tie in to $||T(x)||_{Y} \leq M||x||_{X}$ if $X$ and $Y$ happen to be t.v.s?

Comment: $f\colon X\to Y$ is bounded if $f(B)$ is bounded for every bounded $B\subset X$. If $X,Y$ are locally convex and $X$ is bornological, that implies that bounded linear maps $X\to Y$ are continuous. Normed spaces are bornological. For normed spaces and linear maps, one needs to look only at the unit ball $U$, since every bounded subset is contained in a multiple of that, so if $f(U)$ is bounded (and $f$ is linear!), $f$ is bounded. Then by the homogeneity of linear maps you have $\lVert Tx\rVert_Y \leqslant \lVert x\rVert_X\cdot \sup \{ \lVert Tz\rVert_Y : \lVert z\rVert_X \leqslant 1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that for linear functions on normed spaces, the only functional that is bounded in the usual sense is the zero functional.

Linear is so much more restrictive than say continuous, or even smooth or analytic, that if we also impose the usual definition of boundedness, there is nothing interesting left to study.

Comment: Thank you!  I have one more question: why do we have this definition for functions between metric spaces being bounded?  It can't be for the same reason since these functions don't have to be linear.

Comment: If you mean a function between two general metric spaces $f:X\to Y$, then it's because in a general metric space, points do not have an absolute value. The definition of a bounded, continuous function $g: X \to \Bbb R$, you can just take one point $x \in X$, and evaluate the size of $g(x)$. But in the case of $f(x)$, there is in general no norm on $Y$, so which size should be bounded? It turns out, that the most sensible definition is to say that $f$ is bounded if $d_Y(f(x), f(y))$ is bounded in comparison to $d_X(x, y)$.

Answer (score 2):

If you like, you could rephrase this condition as saying that the map is bounded on the unit sphere.

Comment: This is already answered by Amitai.  A linear map could only be bounded in your sense if it were the zero map.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Batominovski  Would you prefer if I rephrased my answer "Bounded linear maps between normed spaces are so named because they are *bounded* on the unit sphere of the domain"?  His question is entirely about the name of this property of maps.  No one can really know why a particular name is used.  This suggests that the name is consistent with other uses of the word "bounded", if you simply interpret it slightly differently.

Comment: @Batominovski Huh? Of the three answers I see it's the only one that gives an answer to the question (that being a hint why the word "bounded" is used this way.) Maybe you just saw the word "rephrase", and didn't bother to read the post? Understandable, it's sort of long...

Answer (score 1):

If we required $\forall x\in X\quad\|Tx\|_Y\leq M$, there would be no *linear* map satisfying this condition.

Comment: Well, as Arthur points out, there would be *one*...

Comment: Why?  Because if $0 < ||T(x)|| \leq M$, then for some $n \in \Bbb N$, $||T(nx)|| = n||T(x)|| > M$?

Comment: @user46944 Exactly

Comment: @user46944 Yes, this is one way to explain it.

Comment: Nice! I wonder why this hasn't been explained in any of the texts I've looked up on this matter.  Thank you

Comment: I have one more question: why do we have this definition of bounded for functions between metric spaces?  These aren't linear, so it can't be for the same reason.

Comment: @user46944 I'm not familiar with the definition you quoted... When it comes to general metric spaces, as far as I know, a map is bounded if and only if its image is contained in a ball.

Answer (score 0):

A linear function on a normed linear space is continuous everywhere iff it is continuous at the origin. And it is continuous at the origin if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
                    \|x\| < \delta \implies \|Tx\| < \epsilon.
$$
For all $0 < r < 1$, and $x \ne 0$,
$$
              \left\|\frac{r\delta}{\|x\|}x\right\|< \delta \implies
         \left\|T\left(\frac{r\delta}{\|x\|}x\right)\right\| < \epsilon
$$
Therefore,
$$
                   \|Tx\| < \frac{\epsilon}{r\delta}\|x\|,\;\;\; x \ne 0, 0 < r < 1.
$$
Letting $r\rightarrow 1$ gives
$$
                       \|Tx\| \le \frac{\epsilon}{\delta}\|x\|.
$$
Conversely, if $\|Tx\| \le M\|x\|$ for all $x$, then
$$
                \|x\| < \frac{\epsilon}{M+1} \implies \|Tx\| \le M\|x\| < \frac{\epsilon M}{M+1} < \epsilon.
$$
So boundedness of a linear map is equivalent to continuity at $0$, which is equivalent to continuity at every point.